# Win 8 js code security

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

Im developing a win 8 game in js.

When i deploy my app, can any user can see my code files?
My files has some database passwords, i need to ofuscate it?

Comment: You have JavaScript code logging on directly to a database?

Comment: The password is to access a REST service...

Comment: Ah gotcha.  So you're just trying to prevent other things besides your game from using this REST service?

Comment: Yes!!! If you have the endpoint, you can access this... and the endpoint with the password is at a `js` file... But, i want to protect my game from copys too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has access to every source file of your app. You just have to go to *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\* to see all your installed apps. If you have a HTML5 app installed, you'll notice that all the .html and .js files are freely accessible by anyone.

You may want to make a simple C# library that won't be so easy to reverse engineer, and put in it the "security critical" parts of your app. You can see how to integrate C# in HTML/JS apps in this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's not really any good way to prevent people from mucking with your REST service if it's public.  Sure, you can obfuscate things, digitally sign code, pass around certificates, etc.  But in the end it's always possible for someone to reverse engineer your code, emulate a trusted client, or diagnose the network traffic directly.

A better solution here is to focus on mitigating unwanted attacks.  Validate the input coming into each web service call, trust *nothing*, and do a [threat analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_%28computer%29#Threat_analysis) on your API.  For example, if you were writing a Battleship game, have the server keep track of where each ship is and never expose that information to the clients, allowing them to write a fake client that could cheat.  Do the scoring server side, so people can't just post fake scores and get on the high score list.

With that said, unless you're writing the next World of Warcraft, it's unlikely anyone cares enough about your game to jump through any hoops.